# Detete witgets in a class in ttkbootstrap

Tags: python, button, interface, ttk

I am working on a scientific calulator in python and there's a button I want to use to change other buttons in the screen (I want the shift button to change sin,cos and tan to arcsin, arccos, arctan).

```
import tkinter as tk
import ttkbootstrap as ttk
from ttkbootstrap.constants import *


class Master:
    def __init__(self) -> None:
        self.root = ttk.Window(title= "Calculator", themename= "darkly", size=(400,500))
        self.state = True
    
    def print_numbers(self):
        for i, rows in enumerate(self.numbers):
            self.frame_for_the_buttons = ttk.Frame(self.root)
            self.frame_for_the_buttons.pack(fill= BOTH,expand=True)
            for j, buttons in enumerate(rows):
                if buttons in ("shift","**","sqrt","e","π","±","M"):
                    butt = ttk.Button(master= self.frame_for_the_buttons, text=buttons, command= lambda vl=self.numbers[i][j]: self.claculate(vl), style= (WARNING,LINK))
                    butt.pack(side=LEFT, expand=True, fill=BOTH)
                elif buttons in ("deg","sin","cos","tan","log","ln","(",")"):
                    butt = ttk.Button(master= self.frame_for_the_buttons, text=buttons, command= lambda vl=self.numbers[i][j]: self.claculate(vl), style= (SUCCESS,LINK))
                    butt.pack(side=LEFT, expand=True, fill=BOTH)
                elif buttons in ("ac","c","%","/","x","-","+","="):
                    butt = ttk.Button(master= self.frame_for_the_buttons, text=buttons, command= lambda vl=self.numbers[i][j]: self.claculate(vl), style= (INFO,LINK))
                    butt.pack(side=LEFT, expand=True, fill=BOTH)
                else:
                    butt = ttk.Button(master= self.frame_for_the_buttons, text=buttons, command= lambda vl=self.numbers[i][j]: self.claculate(vl), style= (LIGHT, LINK))
                    butt.pack(side=LEFT, expand=True, fill=BOTH)
    
    def claculate(self, num):
        if num == "shift":
            self.state = not(self.state)
            if self.state:
                self.frame_for_the_buttons.destroy()
                self.numbers = [("shift","deg","sin","cos","tan"),
                                ("**","log","ln","(",")"),
                                ("sqrt","ac","c","%","/"),
                                ("e","7","8","9","x"),
                                ("π","4","5","6","-"),
                                ("±","1","2","3","+"),
                                ("M","0",",",".","=")]
                self.print_numbers()
            else:
                self.frame_for_the_buttons.destroy()
                self.numbers = [("shift","deg","arcsin","arccos","arctan"),
                                ("**","log","ln","(",")"),
                                ("sqrt","ac","c","%","/"),
                                ("e","7","8","9","x"),
                                ("π","4","5","6","-"),
                                ("±","1","2","3","+"),
                                ("M","0",",",".","=")]
                self.print_numbers()
    
    def mainloop(self):
        #Entry for numbers and operations
        self.entry_operation = ttk.Entry(master= self.root, style="dark", font= "Arial 40 bold")
        self.entry_operation.pack(side = TOP, fill= X, expand= True)
        
        #Numbers
        self.numbers = [("shift","deg","sin","cos","tan"),
                        ("**","log","ln","(",")"),
                        ("sqrt","ac","c","%","/"),
                        ("e","7","8","9","x"),
                        ("π","4","5","6","-"),
                        ("±","1","2","3","+"),
                        ("M","0",",",".","=")]
        self.print_numbers()
        self.root.mainloop()        
        
win = Master()
win.mainloop()
```

I have tryed to use `.destry()` and `.pack_forget()` but none of the methods worked... I also wonder if there's a more efficient way to do the task other than deleting all buttons and replacing them with the ones I  want even if I only change 3.

Comment: Instead of trying to forget all buttons try applying it to the container `self.frame_for_the_buttons`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found a solution, and is to create another frame for the whole thing and destroying that one, for some reason that works and what I came up before didn't...

```
import tkinter as tk
import ttkbootstrap as ttk
from ttkbootstrap.constants import *


class Master:
    def __init__(self) -> None:
        self.root = ttk.Window(title= "Calculator", themename= "darkly", size=(400,500))
        self.state = True
    
    def print_numbers(self):
        self.frame_for_ev = ttk.Frame(self.root)
        self.frame_for_ev.pack(fill= BOTH,expand=True)
        for i, rows in enumerate(self.numbers):
            self.frame_for_the_buttons = ttk.Frame(self.frame_for_ev)
            self.frame_for_the_buttons.pack(fill= BOTH,expand=True)
            for j, buttons in enumerate(rows):
                if buttons in ("shift","**","sqrt","e","π","±","M"):
                    butt = ttk.Button(master= self.frame_for_the_buttons, text=buttons, command= lambda vl=self.numbers[i][j]: self.claculate(vl), style= (WARNING,LINK))
                    butt.pack(side=LEFT, expand=True, fill=BOTH)
                elif buttons in ("deg","sin","cos","tan","log","ln","(",")"):
                    butt = ttk.Button(master= self.frame_for_the_buttons, text=buttons, command= lambda vl=self.numbers[i][j]: self.claculate(vl), style= (SUCCESS,LINK))
                    butt.pack(side=LEFT, expand=True, fill=BOTH)
                elif buttons in ("ac","c","%","/","x","-","+","="):
                    butt = ttk.Button(master= self.frame_for_the_buttons, text=buttons, command= lambda vl=self.numbers[i][j]: self.claculate(vl), style= (INFO,LINK))
                    butt.pack(side=LEFT, expand=True, fill=BOTH)
                else:
                    butt = ttk.Button(master= self.frame_for_the_buttons, text=buttons, command= lambda vl=self.numbers[i][j]: self.claculate(vl), style= (LIGHT, LINK))
                    butt.pack(side=LEFT, expand=True, fill=BOTH)
    
    def claculate(self, num):
        if num == "shift":
            self.state = not(self.state)
            if self.state:
                self.frame_for_ev.destroy()
                self.numbers = [("shift","deg","sin","cos","tan"),
                                ("**","log","ln","(",")"),
                                ("sqrt","ac","c","%","/"),
                                ("e","7","8","9","x"),
                                ("π","4","5","6","-"),
                                ("±","1","2","3","+"),
                                ("M","0",",",".","=")]
                self.print_numbers()
            else:
                self.frame_for_ev.destroy()
                self.numbers = [("shift","deg","arcsin","arccos","arctan"),
                                ("**","log","ln","(",")"),
                                ("sqrt","ac","c","%","/"),
                                ("e","7","8","9","x"),
                                ("π","4","5","6","-"),
                                ("±","1","2","3","+"),
                                ("M","0",",",".","=")]
                self.print_numbers()
    
    def mainloop(self):
        #Entry for numbers and operations
        self.entry_operation = ttk.Entry(master= self.root, style="dark", font= "Arial 40 bold")
        self.entry_operation.pack(side = TOP, fill= X, expand= True)
        
        #Numbers
        self.numbers = [("shift","deg","sin","cos","tan"),
                        ("**","log","ln","(",")"),
                        ("sqrt","ac","c","%","/"),
                        ("e","7","8","9","x"),
                        ("π","4","5","6","-"),
                        ("±","1","2","3","+"),
                        ("M","0",",",".","=")]
        self.print_numbers()
        self.root.mainloop()        
        
win = Master()
win.mainloop()
```